# How create own qt widget which use qss

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, qtstylesheets

I'm trying to use qss for my own widget. And change style when new style sheet has been loaded. I don't understand how can I fetch colors from current style sheet. And when to update it.

To fetch colors im trying use `palette().color(QPalette::ColorRole::)`. And update it when changeEvent happen:

```cpp
class Widget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Widget(QWidget* parent = nullptr)
        : QWidget(parent), primary(this), background(this) {
            update_brushs();
        }

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
        background.drawRect(event->rect());
        primary.drawText(event->rect(), "hi");

    }

    void changeEvent(QEvent* event) {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::StyleChange) {
            update_brushs();
        }
        QWidget::changeEvent(event);
    }

private:
    void update_brushs() {
        primary.setBrush(palette().color(QPalette::ColorRole::WindowText));
        background.setBrush(palette().color(QPalette::ColorRole::Background));
    }
    QPainter primary;
    QPainter background;
};
```

But i have plain widget

Comment: Any reason why you are using the paintEvent() overload instead of just the stylesheet?

Comment: @TheBadger Because I want create widget with own custom paintEvent and customize this via stylesheet. The question is that: how to access to stylesheet's style (colors) and when need to update cached colors

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is as basic as changing the background color or text color using the stylesheet the following should be able to get you going.

**Widget.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <QWidget>
#include <QStyleOption>
#include <QPainter>

class Widget
  : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    Widget( QWidget* parent = nullptr )
      : QWidget( parent ) {}
    ~Widget() override = default;

    void paintEvent( QPaintEvent* ) override
    {
      QStyleOption opt;
      opt.init( this );
      QPainter p( this );
      style()->drawPrimitive( QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this );
    }
};
```

The above can be tested with the following file:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

#include "Widget.h"

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  QApplication a( argc, argv );
  a.setStyleSheet( "Widget { background-color: blue; }" );

  QWidget one;
  new QVBoxLayout( &one );
  Widget w;
  w.setMinimumSize(200, 200);
  one.show();
  one.layout()->setMargin(20);
  one.layout()->addWidget( &w );

  QPushButton button("Change");
  one.layout()->addWidget( &button );
  QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, &a, [&a](){
    a.setStyleSheet( "Widget { background-color: green; }" );
  });

  return a.exec();
}
```